# How do I let Spring tell me what is wrong with my HQL query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat

We use DAOs that are Interfaces extending JpaRepository in Spring.
Now I have one query that seems alright to me, but deployment fails with a very generic message. I traced it down to this query (see below).

The error message:

```
 Artifact artifact:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Tomcat used to log more details in localhost.log and catalina.log, but they stay empty now and I cannot find out which setting was changed that they do not log anymore. The log settings seem alright to me.

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = localhost.

3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = org.apache.juli.OneLineFormatter


############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager].handlers = 3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/host-manager].handlers = 4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler

# For example, set the org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase logger to log
# each component that extends LifecycleBase changing state:
#org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.level = FINE

# To see debug messages in TldLocationsCache, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for HTTP/2 handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.coyote.http2.level = FINE

# To see debug messages for WebSocket handling, uncomment the following line:
#org.apache.tomcat.websocket.level = FINE
```

And here is the log4j.properties of my webapp:

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, dest1
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.application=DEBUG, dest1
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.application.IndexingUtil=DEBUG, dest1
### log HQL query parser activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=DEBUG

! Log to the console
log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.dest1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dest1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-15.15t] [%-25.25c{1}] %m%n

! LOG TO A FILE
#log4j.appender.dest3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#log4j.appender.dest3.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.dest3.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %d{EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz yyyy} [%-15.15t] [%-25.25c{1}] %m%n

! Specify the file name
#log4j.appender.dest3.File=/path_to_file...

! Control the maximum log file size
log4j.appender.dest3.MaxFileSize=3000KB
log4j.appender.dest3.MaxBackupIndex=50

#log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

Can anyone tell me how to make Spring tell me what is wrong with my deploy?

I narrowed it down to this query:

```java
@Query("select r from Request r join fetch r.categories c join fetch c.criteria d join fetch d.evidences e where r.id = :id")
```

When I reduce it to this it works...

```java
@Query("select r from Request r join fetch r.categories c where r.id = :id")
```

The entity classes are simple classes and their relationship are simple `@OneToMany` relationships with `java.util.List` as Collection type.

I am baffled and cannot see what is wrong. Maybe Spring knows more. 
As far as I know, hibernate allows to fetch a hierarchy like this, but so far no luck.

Comment: change `log4j.appender.dest1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender` to FileAppender and you can see in the logfile what is happend

Comment: @Jens That just reroutes the output form the console to the file, but nothing "new" will show up. The console output is where I got the error message and it does not contain the ParsingException or whatever it is Hibernate throws when it finds an illegal query.

Comment: Why you know that is a hibernate related problem?

Comment: Well it is either Hibernate or Spring. I frankly don't know which one parses those Queries from the annotations and checks their syntax. But it is definitely that query.

Comment: @Boldbayar I cannot really catch anything, because this happens during deployment, so I cannot really put a try catch around that.

Comment: I don't really see anything particularly wrong. In these cases I'd start with going back to the most minimal log4j configuration possible and see if the error logging returns or not. If it does then its a matter of slowly putting back bits of the logging configuration until it disappears again, then you know what triggers it.